# SQL Server is throwing an error: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I have this situation, I'm trying to call a stored procedure to return a list of tasks, with the `ProjectId` null. I tested the stored procedure and it is working, but on the code not. What am I doing wrong?

The view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Tasks)
    {
        @if (item.ProjectId == null)
        {
            <tr data-toggle="RecEdit" data-url="@(Url.Action("Edit") + "/" + item.TaskId)">
                <td style="width: 20%">@item.Title</td>
                <td style="width: 20%">@item.Description</td>
            </tr>
        }

    }
```

This is the model class:

```
public class CreateTaskVM
{
    public Task task {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Project> projects {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProjectStatus> StatusTypes { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
public IActionResult RecTask()
{
        CreateTaskVM mytasks = new CreateTaskVM();

        var param = new SqlParameter("@ProjectId", "Null");
        mytasks.Tasks = context.Task.FromSql($"EXEC [dbo].[uspGET_Tasks] @ProjectId", param).ToList();

        return View(mytasks);
}
```

Also I was trying to do it in Identity but for some reason the MV come null. I just want to present a list of tasks with the value of `ProjectId` is null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Null" sure looks like a string there.

Comment: `new SqlParameter("@ProjectId", "Null");` should probably be changed to `new SqlParameter("@ProjectId", System.DBNull);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SqlParameter contains the string `"Null"`.

If you want to send a null value to a stored procedure, try using `DBNull.Value`:

```
var param = new SqlParameter("@ProjectId", DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: Perfect the errors gone but the Count = 0 which the list come with no tasks. I put the view.

Comment: @JonathanPadilla That is a separate issue. You shouldn't change your question once it has been answered, you need to open a new question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new at this but I'll open other question and thank you for your response!

Answer (score -1):

You have to make your propery "projectId" as a nullable property.

Comment: The property "ProjectId" is a string not need to put nullable.